# Using setState inside a arrow function resets state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I am trying to modify a state when a users input fields on my dashboard is changed. This is  how the handler is intended to work:

1. If the state is empty. Create a user with the standard values and change its values to the changed inputs
2. If the user exists in the state, change the changed field in the state to the new value.
3. If the user does not exist. Add the user to the state and change the changed field to the new value.

I am doing this by calling this function on a change of any inputs:

```js
const handleInputChange = (event, person) => {
        let new_form_val = {
            objectId: person._id,
            name: person.name,
            role: person.role,
            privilege: person.privilege,
            group: person.group
        };
    
        console.log("handle change function called")
    
    
        if (formValues.length == 0)
        {
            console.log("formValues is empty")
            new_form_val[event.target.name] = event.target.value
            console.log("adding", new_form_val)
            setFormValues([...formValues, new_form_val])
        }
            
    
        // console.log(event.target.value)
        
        console.log("Change target id", event.target.id)
        console.log("current formvalue before change", formValues)
    
        let form_val = formValues.find((item) => item.objectId == event.target.id)
    
        if (form_val) {
            console.log("person found in formValues", form_val)
    
            let index = formValues.indexOf(form_val)
            formValues[index][event.target.name] = event.target.value
            console.log("Changed already existing formvalue", formValues)
            setFormValues(formValues)

        } 
        else {
            new_form_val[event.target.name] = event.target.value
            console.log("new person in form value", new_form_val)
            setFormValues([...formValues, new_form_val])
        }
    
    }
```

Later on I am using that function as an onChange event handler

```js
    useEffect(() => {   
        // GARL: https: //bobbyhadz.com/blog/react-push-to-state-array
            setPeople([])
            console.log("get users effetct ran")
            
            axios.get('/api/getusers').then((response) => {
                response.data.forEach((item, index) => {
                    setPeople(oldStatusArray => {
                        return [...oldStatusArray, <Person
                            key={index}
                            id={index+1}
                            _id={item._id}
                            name={item.name}
                            role={item.role}
                            privilege_id={item.privilege}
                            group_id={item.group}
                            onChange={(event) => handleInputChange(event, item)}
                        />]
                    })
                
                }); 
            })

    }, []);
```

The problem I am facing though is whenever the onChange function is called. The whole formValues sate is reset and replaced with the new changed state. For exmpale: I change user A to a new name and role and the change is logged to the console. I also Change User B and then C to a new group. Finally the state only has the changes made from C.

Here is the full code:

```js
import Link from 'next/link';
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Person from '../components/person' // Not actually a import

const Dashboard = () => {
    const [people, setPeople] = useState([]);
    const [formValues, setFormValues] = useState([]);
    

    const handleInputChange = (event, person) => {
        let new_form_val = {
            objectId: person._id,
            name: person.name,
            role: person.role,
            privilege: person.privilege,
            group: person.group
        };
    
        console.log("handle change function called")
    
    
        if (formValues.length == 0)
        {
            console.log("formValues is empty")
            new_form_val[event.target.name] = event.target.value
            console.log("adding", new_form_val)
            setFormValues([...formValues, new_form_val])
        }
            
    
        // console.log(event.target.value)
        
        console.log("Change target id", event.target.id)
        console.log("current formvalue before change", formValues)
    
        let form_val = formValues.find((item) => item.objectId == event.target.id)
    
        if (form_val) {
            console.log("person found in formValues", form_val)
    
            let index = formValues.indexOf(form_val)
            formValues[index][event.target.name] = event.target.value
            console.log("Changed already existing formvalue", formValues)
            setFormValues(formValues)

        } 
        else {
            new_form_val[event.target.name] = event.target.value
            console.log("new person in form value", new_form_val)
            setFormValues([...formValues, new_form_val])
        }
    
    }

    useEffect(() => {   
            setPeople([])
            console.log("get users effetct ran")
            
            axios.get('/api/getusers').then((response) => {
                response.data.forEach((item, index) => {
                    setPeople(oldStatusArray => {
                        return [...oldStatusArray, <Person
                            key={index}
                            _id={item._id}
                            name={item.name}
                            role={item.role}
                            privilege_id={item.privilege}
                            group_id={item.group}
                            onChange={(event) => handleInputChange(event, item)}
                        />]
                    })
                
                }); 
            })

    }, []);

    const submit = (values) => {
        // Submits state to backend for handling
    }

    return (
          <div id="main">
               <h1>Administration</h1>
               {(people.length == 0) ? 
                 <h1>Laddar innehållet..</h1> : people }
          </div>    
    );
  }
  
  export default Dashboard;
```

Here is the output after changing the input fields a couple of times:

```
>> handle change function called

>> formValues is empty

>> adding - Object { objectId: "634ea9b368bd856cebfdddc0", name: "RADICATED", role: "...", privilege: "634ff6d42c7b67c5708e901b", group: "634ff7322c7b67c5708e901d" }

>> change target id 634ea9b368bd856cebfdddc0 

>> current formvalue before change - Array []

>> new person in form value - Object { objectId: "634ea9b368bd856cebfdddc0", name: "RADICATED", role: "....", privilege: "634ff6d42c7b67c5708e901b", group: "634ff7322c7b67c5708e901d" }

>> CURRENT formvalues - Array [ {…} ] (len: 1)
```

I have also tried to adding `formValues` as a dependency to `useEffect` however, this results in a rerender of the users if I change any of the inputs as the setPeople is called in the useEffect.

How can I achieve a `handleInputChange` function that works as intended without updating the renderer or reseting the state?

Answer (score 1):

I noticed the step 1 and 3 are actually the same so I put those together. The `itemExists` check if the person is already in the state. If the state is empty `itemExists` is false and if the person does not exists `itemExists` is also false.

When false we just update the field and return the previous and the new `new_form_val`.

When true we loop over all the current values until we find the one we want to edit, and then update the field we want to update.

```js
const handleInputChange = (event, person) => {
  const new_form_val = {
    objectId: person._id,
    name: person.name,
    role: person.role,
    privilege: person.privilege,
    group: person.group,
  };

  // check if the item already exists
  const itemExists =
    formValues.find((item) => item.objectId == event.target.id) !== undefined;

  if (itemExists) {
    setFormValues((prevFormValues) => {
      // map current values
      const newValues = prevFormValues.map((item) => {
        // if its not the item we're editing just return the item
        if (item.objectId !== event.target.id) return item;
        // if it is, update the item
        const updatedItem = {
          ...item,
          [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
        };
        return updatedItem;
      });
      return newValues;
    });
  } else {
    // update the field with the new value
    new_form_val[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
    // add to the values
    setFormValues((prevFormValues) => [...prevFormValues, new_form_val]);
  }
};
```

I also updated the way the people were set. Now we first loop over all the data received from the api and create an array of Person components and set that array to the state, instead of setting the state for every result in the api data.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  // no need to set the people to an empty array since the default state is already an empty array
  // setPeople([]);

  console.log("get users effetct ran");

  axios.get("/api/getusers").then((response) => {
    const peopleFromApi = response.data.map((item, index) => (
      <Person
        key={index}
        _id={item._id}
        name={item.name}
        role={item.role}
        privilege_id={item.privilege}
        group_id={item.group}
        onChange={(event) => handleInputChange(event, item)}
      />
    ));

    setPeople(peopleFromApi);
  });
}, []);
```

I hope this helps you continue your project!

Comment: I have been banging my head against the wall for a while! Works great. Also good catch about the  duplicate check!